# Recommend alternatives / similar Software for Beyond Compare

Tags: compare, winmerge

Keep using beyond compare, but it is not available in my new environment, i am trying WinMerge but i have an error when i try to compare two big text files , 170 Mo for each file.
i know there is only 5 or 6 different lines in this files.

```
The message given correspond to the Error code :
#: Merge.rc:2421
#, c-format
msgid "An error occurred while comparing the files."
msgstr "Erreur lors de la comparaison des fichiers."
```

I'm using the last 2.14.0 version

1.Can this issue be resolved?
2.If no, any alternative software?

Comment: Your question #1 is a user support question not a programming question.  Your question #2 is off-topic, as it is a request for a software recommendation.

Comment: My question was updated

Comment: Noted.  However, it is still off-topic for the reasons stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Eclipse to perform the comparation:

1.Copy the file/folder you want to compare into workspace of Eclipse.
2.Select the file/folder you want to compare
3.

```
CTRL+3
```

or
Type in Compare with other resource in "Quick Access" lineditor in right corner.
4.Select the target

When #4, Actually you can modify the source you selected, so For #1,#2, can just randomly select some file in your project.

You can also achieve this by select two items, right click-> Compare with-> Each other

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you and it works fine